# Resizing root partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am running a Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot and I'm trying to resizing my `/` as it's running out of space.

I've shrunk my other NTFS partition and freed 10GB of unallocated space, when I go to gparted it doesn't seem to let me to resize the ext4 partition using the unallocated space I freed up earlier. I don't have any other partition on the Ubuntu side other than the swap and the ext4, and the rest is my Windows's NTFS partitions.

[image: gparted]

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: The space you've freed is located _behind_ the rest of your partitions. To be added to your root partition it should be adjacent to it. Don't be mislead by partitions' ordinal numbers, only their location on the disk matters.

Comment: yeah, i've worked it out thanks to M. Yigci, thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

So I actually figured it out and in-case someone is in the same boots as I am, here's how I've done it :

1. Free some space on your HDD that is directly next to your Linux partition, in my case, I took 10GBs from `Data` partition, as it's the one directly next to my Linux partition.

I've done it by moving the chunks of data in my `Data` partition to the right and free some space in the left side (the one next to the Linux partition), and note that you have to unmount the partition before you can modify it.  And it took about 90 minutes for me to move the 172GB data chunks to the right.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfwEd.png)

2. After that, left-click on your swap partition and click `swapoff`
3. Now, you can resize the `ext4` partition using the space you freed before
4. Apply changes.

I've resized the `ext4` partition on a LiveCD, but I don't think it's necessary. (you can resize it while logged in)

Answer (score -1):

You can extend partitions only which harddrive sectors are neighbours. i mean in this case you can not keep any partition between the root part and unlocated space.

As i can see the only expandable partition is the one named Telkom Stuff and it is most probably the drive you make space from. If you want to expand your root part, you need to reconfigure disk. Using an external harddrive you can backup your data and do whatever you want with your disk by deleting Data and Telkom Stuff partitions. If there is another way I'd like to know too.

Comment: so kinda like the blocks start and end positions that's have to be side-by-side only? what if i allocate the 10gb back to Telkom Stuff and take 10GB from "Data" instead ?

Comment: Yes. You are right. If you do that nothing will change. 10GB data block will be placed between Data and Telkom Stuff partitions. So you can't be able extend ext4 part. As i said before only thing you can do (according to my knowledge) is using an external hard drive and freeup data partition and delete. When you do that you can be able to extend ext4 part up to 11+182gb. Take how much memory you want for Ubuntu and create a ntfs partition to use as Data disk in Windows again.

Comment: Actually, I've done just that.. Your idea of the neighbouring sectors gave me a way to work around it.. I'll post how later, thanks !